# OpenMAX, Raspberry PI: Get Video Dimensions of H264

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, h.264, openmax

is there any way to get the video dimensions of a *H264* video on the raspberry pi using *OpenMAX* directly **without** having to use *ffmpeg* or something else? All the pi examples appear to have hardcoded values for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible by querying the OMX_PARAM_PORTDEFINITIONTYPE structure of the decoder output port. You have to use something along these lines:

```
OMX_PARAM_PORTDEFINITIONTYPE portdef;
portdef.nSize = sizeof(OMX_PARAM_PORTDEFINITIONTYPE);
portdef.nVersion.nVersion = OMX_VERSION;
portdef.nPortIndex = 131;

OMX_GetParameter(ILC_GET_HANDLE(video_decode), OMX_IndexParamPortDefinitionType, portdef);

printf("Width: %d, Height: %d\n", portdef.format.video.nFrameWidth, portdef.format.nFrameHeight);
```

Please note that this will only give you correct values after the OMX_EventPortSettingsChanged event has fired (which happens after processing the first buffer). Otherwise, this values can and probably will be wrong.